# Array as struct database?

Tags: c

I have a struct that reads data from the user:

```
typedef struct
{
    int seconds;
} Time;

typedef struct
{
    Time time;
    double distance;
 } Training;


 Training input;

 scanf("%d %lf", input.time.seconds, input.distance);
```

This scanf will be looped and the user can input different data every time, I want to store this data in an array for later use. I THINK I want something like arr[0].seconds and arr[0].distance.

I tried to store the entered data in an array but it didn't really work at all...

```
Training data[10];

data[10].seconds = input.time.seconds;
data[10].distance = input.distance;
```

The data will wipe when the program closes and that's how I like it to be. So I want it to be stored in an array, no files or databases!

Comment: When you declare `Training data[10];`, you can only access elements 0..9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, the training set has a 'time' field to access the seconds, and if you define an array of 10 element, you can only use data[0] to data[9], data[10] will be past the end of the array.

```
Training data[10];

data[0].time.seconds = input.time.seconds;
data[0].distance = input.distance;

....

data[9].time.seconds = input.time.seconds;
data[9].distance = input.distance;
```

Answer (score 1):

`data[10]` is of type `Training` which does not have `seconds`. Try:

```
Training data[10];

data[10].time.seconds = input.time.seconds;
data[10].distance = input.distance;
```

Comment: You can't use subscript 10 on an array `Training data[10];` because the valid subscripts run from 0 to 9.